# Alternate methods to invite friends to facebook

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-page

I am working on a fan page and currently I am using an iframe app with the facebook send button embedded in it. I was wondering if there was a better way to invite people to a fan page, like a dialog box that opens with the list of the users friends, the user  can then choose his/her friends and send invites. Is this still possible, since FBML tags have been deprecated. Thank you.

Regards
Ghulam Mustafa Majal

Answer (score 1):

You can use our [requests channel](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/) if you're making an iframe app on facebook which will allow your user to select and send a 'request' to their friends. Then you'll just want to make sure and how the like button on your landing page so when other users receive the request, they can like your fan page as desired.